# fstream file empty (easy small code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

i made this easy code to try this `fstream file ("....txt")`  but the **file stays empty** !
can someone please help ?
(note that i have a **"selfmade" header** file that includes all the files i normally use and the namespace)

This small programm should cout everything from the **File.txt** and then give you the chance to type new lines to the file, to break the cin progress you use break. but like i said the file stays empty

```
#include <myHead.h>

int main()
{
    string line;
    int i;
    fstream myFile ("File.txt");

    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myFile,line))
        {
            cout << line << "\n";
        }

        line = "0";

        for(line;line!="break";cin >> line)
    {
        if(line != "break")
            myFile << line;
    }

        myFile.close();

    }
    else
        cout << "error, File.txt cannot be opened!";

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just a few pet peeve from me. `myFile.close();` is not needed. RAII idiom means `fstream` object will close and handle the resources.

Comment: ok thx.any reason for that? i know it always works without but i think its just good stil to close, isnt it?

Comment: Research C++ RAII idiom.

Comment: Oh and the solution to your problem is your not flushing the fstream i think. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you finish reading the file, the file is in a state of "end of file reached", which is not *good*.

You will need to reset the stream state before writing (appending). This is accomplished with the stream method `clear()`.

Also, you may want to explicitly open the file as both input and output:  `ios::in | ios::out`.

Comment: yo thanks! that worked! but why ios::in and ios::out ? this is the standard of fstream isnt it?

Comment: and another small question : now when i write for example : hello, how are you? the program "replaces" the blanks with enter, so there are only single words and no sentences but i dont want to use hello,_how_are_you?

Comment: oh, i just have to use getline. thanks for youre help, andre's too! topic can be closed

Comment: As I said, the `ios::in | ios::out` would be an **explicit** file mode, letting readers know that you are opening the file for both input and output.  Some people may not remember that `fstream` default is both.  The explicit text does not harm code production but does improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Even though its been already answered I want to point out a better option of ending the input. If you do it as such:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    std::fstream file("file");
    std::string buf;

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "READ:" << "\n\n";
        while (getline(file, buf))
        {
            std::cout << buf << "\n";
        }

        file.clear();

        std::cout << '\n' << "WRITE:" << "\n\n";
        while (getline(std::cin, buf))
        {
            file << '\n' << buf;
            file.seekp(0, file.end);
            file.seekg(0, file.end);
        }

        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error, file could not be opened.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you can end the stream by pressing `Ctrl+Z + Enter` on windows or `Ctrl+D` on UNIXes.